# Old value in multiple select option in laravel

Tags: laravel

**Here is my select option**

```
 <select name="category[]" id="categories"
class="js-example-basic-single form-control"multiple>
@foreach ($category as $element)
<option value=" {{$element->id}}}"{{ (old("category[]") == $element->id ? "selected":"") }}>
{{$element->name}}
</option>
 @endforeach

  </select>
```

I can't get the old value ,What I'm doing wrong?
how can i get the old value ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories" class="js-example-basic-single form-control"multiple>
    @foreach ($category as $element)
      <option value=" {{$element->id}} " {{ (collect(old('category'))->contains($element->id)) ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ $element->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not named `category[]` on the server side, that is just notation to turn it into an array; it is named `category`.

As Kamlesh Paul has stated you can use `in_array` to check against the possible values of the old input array:

```
{{ in_array($element->id, (array) old('category', [])) ? "selected" : "" }}
```

Comment: but it's must be array`category[]` if not I will get bug:"( from the controller

Comment: again ... `name="category[]"` is just a special notation so PHP will use the input as an array ... on the server side it is just `category` which is an array

Answer (score 0):

you can try `in_array()`
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

```php
<select name="category[]" id="categories" class="js-example-basic-single form-control" multiple>
    @foreach ($category as $element)
    <option value=" {{$element->id}}}" {{  in_array($element->id ,old("category",[]) ? "selected":"") }}>
        {{$element->name}}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: it's not working :"( ,in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: then try `old("category[]")` may be it is array

Comment: Sorry i don't get you=( , what do you mean ?

Comment: @Phú just try this if works then try to understand what is going on